# SQL Alchemy Relationship not linking classes

Tags: sqlalchemy

I have two classes:

```
class Country(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'country'
    country_id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True)
    cities = relationship('city',back_populates='country')
class City(Base):
    __tablename__='city'
    country_id = Column(BigInteger,ForeignKey('country.country_id'))
    country = relationship("country",back_populates='cities')

    city_id = Column(BigInteger,primary_key=True) 
    x=Column(BigInteger)
    y=Column(BigInteger)
```

Now, when I create a country object:

```
c1 = City(x=0,y=0)
c2 = City(x=5,y=2)
country = Country(cities = [c1,c2])
```

and call

```
print(c1.country_id)
```

> None

How do I fix this?
Thanks!

Comment: @mechanical_meat I  have the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script below works.  There are two changes from that in the question

- Change the relationship to match the basic [one-to-many relationship](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/basic_relationships.html#one-to-many) from the docs
- Add the instance to a session and flush to obtain ids from the database
- Change the primary keys from `BigInteger` to `Integer`

Changing the types of the primary keys from `BigInteger` to `Integer` is necessary on SQLite, but not on MariaDB (MySQL) or Postgresql.

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy import orm

Base = orm.declarative_base()


class Country(Base):
    __tablename__ = "country"
    country_id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    cities = orm.relationship("City")


class City(Base):
    __tablename__ = "city"
    country_id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey("country.country_id"))

    city_id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    x = sa.Column(sa.Integer)
    y = sa.Column(sa.Integer)


engine = sa.create_engine("sqlite://", echo=True)

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
session = orm.Session(engine)


c1 = City(x=0, y=0)
c2 = City(x=5, y=2)
country = Country(cities=[c1, c2])
session.add(country)
session.flush()


print(c1.country_id)
```